# UNIX KSH - Using double quotes or no quotes when assigning strings with wildcard to a variable?

Tags: shell-script, quoting, wildcards, ksh

I am new to UNIX and currently working on a shell script where I will be receiving files with names such as `abc_123_date.zip` so the file names will be `abc_123_12312005`. Instead of hardcoding `abc_123_*.zip` in commands such as `find` and `if [ -f ... ]` all over, I plan to store that string in a variable and then use it. For example:

```
file_name=abc_123_*.zip
```

And then in rest of the sections of the code I can use `$file_name` instead of the actual string for any and all operations which requires that string.

What is the best way to store that string:

```
Option 1: file_name=abc_123_*.zip

Option 2: file_name="abc_123_*.zip"
```

Which is the better option? and why?

Thanks!

Comment: The space before the `=` does not look right. Is it OK on `ksh`? It is not in bash. (I can't see how it could reliably parse it).

Comment: Yes, it's not okay in ksh. I was just trying provide an example on that line. The actual options do not have any.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to preference in that it doesn't matter to the shell as far as the filename wildcards are concerned. Filename expansion and word splitting don't happen in a regular (non-array) assignment, regardless of if the quotes are there or not.

Though in many other contexts you'd need the quotes, and you'd also need them in an assignment if the value contains whitespace or shell operators (e.g. `;`, `(`, `>` etc.). So some might want to use them here, too, just to use the same custom everywhere.

See also: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: Thank you for your input!

Comment: Note that globbing is not performed in `array=([0]=* [1]=???)` (ksh93 syntax) either. Quoting would be needed in `array=('*' '???')` simple zsh-like  syntax.